# How does "PHP Extended Support" work?

Tags: php

Some big providers like *1&1* or *Stratos* sell **"PHP Extended Support"** to their customers. These practices have caused - for good reason - a lot of controversy, but this is not the topic.

Do they have specialized teams for developing new security patches and fixes for the older deprecated versions of PHP? Or are there commercial external services one can purchase on the market? If so, do you know of enterprises providing that kind of service?

Most projects are easy to move forward to recent versions, I know. But I'm interested in the edge cases, where it's just too much trouble and you want to keep the thing running for another year.

Comment: Found out that *Zend* offers LTS-packages: 
https://www.zend.com/services/php-long-term-support

Answer (score 3):

As per https://www.ionos.com/help/hosting/troubleshooting-for-php/php-extended-support/ 1&1 appear to have their own team backporting vulnerability patches into PHP for their clients.

Its likely not that they develop new packages, but likely they assess vulnerabilities on new versions,  look to see if they exist in the old version and patch the versions they support if it does.